# How do I setup VSCODE to create Maven projects?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I recently installed Visual Studio Code and am now trying to create a Maven project. When I first tried to create a Maven project, I received an error about the JAVA_HOME setting, so I fixed that. Next I received an error saying it couldn't find an executable or script file in the Maven > Executable: Path folder. I disabled the setting named Maven > Executable: Prefer Maven Wrapper, and then I changed found the mvnw.cmd file and added the path to that folder to my settings (shown below):

```
C:\Users\user1\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-maven-0.21.4\resources\maven-wrapper
```

Now when I try to create the Maven project, I just get the following in TERMINAL window and no project is created:

```
>> cd "c:\Users\user1\Documents\Bidi\Source\Maven"
>> & "C:\Users\user1\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-maven-0.21.4\resources\maven-wrapper\" org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId="maven-archetype-quickstart" -DarchetypeGroupId="org.apache.maven.archetypes" -DarchetypeVersion="1.4"
>> "
```

Has anyone seen this problem and figured out how to fix it?

Comment: could it be that instead of setting the maven-wrapper directory, it needs you to configure the path of a maven installation? documentation says that there is a property maven.executable.path where you should cofigure the path of the "mvn" executable

Comment: Hi Petrubear, I did set the Maven > Executable: Path in the VSCODE settings. Is that the same as the maven.executable.path property?

Comment: FYI: [*Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code*](https://inside.java/2023/10/18/announcing-vscode-extension/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve the issue. After looking at Microsoft's troubleshooting page on GitHub here (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-maven/blob/master/Troubleshooting.md), I searched for folders containing "apache-maven". I was then able to find the folder with the mvn file. I then entered the full path, including the file name in the maven.executable.path property and it worked. The full path was like this:

```
C:\Users\user1\.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\abc123abc123abc123XX\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\mvn
```

Comment: This might work for other users https://maven.apache.org/install.html

Answer (score 9):

Step 1 - Verify Java Installation on your Machine
Open console and execute the following java command.

OS  Task    Command
-Windows    Open Command Console    c:> java -version
-Linux  Open Command Terminal   $ java -version
-Mac    Open Terminal   machine:~ joseph$ java -version
Let's verify the output for all the operating systems −

If you do not have Java installed, install the Java Software Development Kit (SDK) from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html. We are assuming Java 1.7.0.60 as installed version for this tutorial.

Step 2 - Set JAVA Environment
Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the base directory location where Java is installed on your machine. For example −

OS  Output
Windows Set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60
Linux   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java-current
Mac export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
Append Java compiler location to System Path.

Verify Java Installation using java -version command as explained above.

Step 3 - Download Maven Archive
Download Maven 2.2.1 from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi.

OS  Archive name
Windows apache-maven-3.3.1-bin.zip
Linux   apache-maven-3.3.1-bin.tar.gz

Step 4 - Extract the Maven Archive
Extract the archive, to the directory you wish to install Maven 3.3.1. The subdirectory apache-maven-3.3.1 will be created from the archive.

OS  Location (can be different based on your installation)
Windows C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.1
Linux   /usr/local/apache-maven

Step 5 - Set Maven Environment Variables
Add M2_HOME, M2, MAVEN_OPTS to environment variables.

OS  Output
Windows 
Set the environment variables using system properties.

M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.1 M2=%M2_HOME%\bin MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m

Linux
Open command terminal and set environment variables.

export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.1 export M2=$M2_HOME/bin

export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m

export M2=$M2_HOME/bin

export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m

Step 6 - Add Maven bin Directory Location to System Path
Now append M2 variable to System Path.

OS  Output
Windows Append the string ;%M2% to the end of the system variable, Path.
Linux   export PATH=$M2:$PATH
Mac export PATH=$M2:$PATH

Step 7 - Verify Maven Installation
Now open console and execute the following mvn command.

OS  Task    Command
Windows Open Command Console    c:> mvn --version
Linux   Open Command Terminal   $ mvn --version

Finally, verify the output of the above commands, which should be as follows −

Comment: Why do we have to do this in 2024 (or later)? Why isn't there an installer that does this?